# How can I prevent jvm exit in camel component code

Tags: apache-camel

I'm writing a camel component to support SMB3 protocol, after imitating camel-ftp, I found my smb component can not keep running just like that camel-ftp did, because after camel context statred, main thread exited and jvm exited. I can't find the configuretions in camel component consumer.

So in camel custom component code, how can I prevent context just exit after I started the smb schedulers?

Answer (score 0):

You can hold main thread using java CountDownLatch. I use CountDownLatch in my camel junit test.